# Hibernate won't initialize proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy

I've got this mappings in Hibernate (through JPA, using EntityManager and such):

```
 public ChildClass {

     ....
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "parentClassId")
        private ParentClass parentClass;
     ....
    }
```

And a parent class that has a list of `ChildClass` elements:

```
 public ParentClass {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentClass", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<ChildClass> childElements;
    ...

    }
```

Now I have this method in my Service layer:

```
@Transactional
public ChildClassDTO consultarPuntuacionPrueba(Long parentClassId) {
            ChildClass result= childClassDAO.getChildClassByParentId(parentClassId);



            ParentClass parentClass = result.getParentClass();

            System.out.println("UNITIALIZED: " + ((HibernateProxy)prueba).getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized());


            Long parentClassId = parentClass.getParentClassId();
            Boolean anAttribute = parentClass.getBooleanAttribute();

            return map(result, ChildClassDTO.class);
        }
```

The problem is -- parentClass is a javassist proxy, and even though when accessing a getter of `parentClass`, I can see a query getting executed (it shows in my console), the proxy never gets initialized and holds null for all attributes... I have tried said query directly towards my database, and it returns the expected data.

I know Hibernate must return a proxy when I call `childClass.getParentClass()`, but why is it never initialized afterwards?

Comment: Is "parentClassId" the fk column name in the database?

Comment: Yes, mapping works okay in other instances... Weird thing is, this is happening with most of my relations

Comment: Do you use the `final` keyword somewere in your entities?

Comment: As a matter of fact -- I do! And now I think I can see what's happening -- Proxies cannot inject anything because they cannot override the setter methods right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your don't use the `final` keyword for your entities getters and setters otherwise the proxies will not be able to override the methods and may not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you defined in the mapping, Hibernate loads the mapped entity lazily. That means the mapped entity is only loaded when you access it (otherwise you only have a proxy instance). So you could change the FetchType to EAGER if you would like that the mapped entity is eagerly loaded (without a proxy)

Comment: That's not my question -- as I stated in my OP, I know it's lazily loaded and Im okay with that, the problem is *after* accessing the proxies' properties, I still get null values cause the proxy won't get initialized even after the proper query has been made

Comment: That is indeed very strange